# VB BMI Calculater that calculates average weight of all users

Tags: vb.net

I have a BMI calculator currently that is the easy part the problem is I have no idea of how to go about adding a function to calculate the average weight of all users. I am using a register and login system also which stores the username and password as strings.

Any help/solutions would be appreciated

Comment: I will re-iterate I have it all working apart from the average weight of all users after all users have registered. I'm talking about storing the data and then on each individual login for different users being able to calculate the average weight of all users

Comment: Well, Average is calculated as the *sum of all items divided by the number of items*. How you would implement it depends on what technology you are using, how/where you want it shown or used. A solution for a database calculation will most likely be different to a solution for a GUI app. The first thing would be for you to decide when and how the value is to be used. Do everything but leave a gap where the Average value needs to be. Then you will have an idea of what your next step needs to be.

Comment: In addition, you should also take the Tour and read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you Jay , it's for a GUI app, I really appreciate your input :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a class to store the user info an weight something like this ..

```
Private Class User
    Public Property UserName As String
    Public Property Password As String
    Public Property Weight As Double
End Class
```

and you have a list of users like this

```
Private Users As New List(Of User)
```

then this function will return the average weight of all the users

```
Private Function GetAverageUserWeight() As Double
    Dim totalWeight As Double
    For Each person As User In Users
        totalWeight += person.Weight
    Next
    Return totalWeight / Users.Count
End Function
```

Used like this

```
Dim avWeight As Double
avWeight = GetAverageUserWeight()
```

Comment: Thank you David, I really appreciate your help :)